# Steps to move from paypal to Stripe?

Tags: payment-processor, paypal, recurring-contributions, stripe

If I move from paypal to stripe, what steps or information I need to take into consideration in terms of recurring contribution? And how to initiate the moving existing recurring contribution profiles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to reach out to Paypal and Stripe directly to ask them about how to initiate the process of transferring your recurring giving.  I would suggest inventorying your existing recurring records in Paypal first, to see how complex the data is; in a recent transition to Stripe, we encountered some challenges with constituents who had multiple payment profiles.  The more clarification you can get from Stripe about what will be required, I think the more smoothly this will go for you.  (Typically the processors would need to transfer the payment details directly.)

Hope this helps,
Lesley